# Integration using substitution: $ I_n = \int^2_0 x^n\sqrt{1+2x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

$$ I_n = \int^2_0 x^n\sqrt{1+2x^2} dx$$
I have proved that for $ n\geq 2$
$$ (2n+4)I_n = 27*2^{n-1} -(n-1)I_{n-2} $$

Now I have to prove the following result

**Question**

Use a suitable substitution to show that 
$$ I_0=3+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\ln({1+\sqrt2}) $$

Is there any way to solve this without using hyperbolic functions? I have tried substituting tan theta, cos theta, sin theta but nothing works out. Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: $$\sqrt2x=\tan t$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'll try

Comment: I am getting sec^3 t in the integral. How to solve that?

Comment: @FaiqRaees Since the problem seems to be solved, you might want to [mark one of the answers as accepted](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark (✓) icon next to the answer on the left. Doing so will mark the question as answered, and will also award both you and the author of the answer a few reputation points.

Comment: Done. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I_0=\int_0^2 \sqrt{1+2x^2}dx$$
Use substitution $x=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\tan\theta$. $dx=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\sec^2\theta$.
$$\begin{align} I_0 
& = \int_0^{\tan^{-1}(2\sqrt2)}\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}\cdot\sec^2\theta d\theta\\ 
& = \int_0^{\tan^{-1}(2\sqrt2)}\frac1{\sqrt2}\sec^3\theta d\theta \\
\end{align}$$
To evaluate this integral, use the fact that $$\int \sec^3xdx=\frac{\sin x \sec^2 x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int\sec xdx \tag{1}$$
and the fact that $\sec x$ integrates to $\log(\tan x+\sec x)$.

---

The equation $(1)$ can be derived by integration by parts on $\sec^3 x=\sec x \cdot \sec^2 x$.
$$\begin{align}\int \sec^3 x dx  & = \int \sec x \sec^2 x dx\\
& = \sec x \tan x -\int\sec x \tan^2 x dx\\
& = \sec^2 x \sin x - \int\sec^3x-\sec x dx
\end{align}\\$$
$$\implies 2\int \sec^3 x dx=\sec^2 x \sin x +\int \sec x dx$$

Comment: Can you tell me which identity you used when you got the sinxsec^2x term

Comment: @FaiqRaees Edited to include this.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute $$\sqrt{1+2x^2}=t-x\sqrt{2}$$.

Comment: I am not really sure how to use that substitution. The substitution I have mainly dealt have x as the subject. (Or the main variable as the subject)

Comment: Square both sides, reduce $2x^2$, compute $x$ and $dx$ and so on. Having $x$ we have of course $\sqrt{1+2x^2}$ as a function of $t$. It is enough to integrate a certain rational function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

There are are two "tricky tricks" that you can exploit:

$$(\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}))'=\frac{1+\dfrac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
and
$$(x\sqrt{x^2+1})'=\sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=2\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

Hence by addition,

$$2\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+x\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$